# is google play game services API open-source?

Tags: google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

I need to develop my own auto-search criteria for realtime multiplayer matches.
I have already copied the whole class of the realtime multiplayer example into my project and tested it.
Problem is: The only criteria i can specify on google play game services API is the number of players. I want the player to fight another player but only if they are on the same level(the levels of the players will be stored on a database). How can i do it? Is the source code of the api somewhere i can download so i can extend some class?

Comment: Maybe you would like to star this. https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=87&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Platform%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 0):

It is not open source.

If your level matching is strict (i.e. someone level 7 can only play other level 7s), then you could use the room variant.  If it's a looser match (i.e. someone level 7 can play people from level 5 through 9), maybe you could actually join a number of different rooms at once.